# How to set Limit to image zoom wp8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, zooming, limit

I want to set limit on zoom so that after a certain level of zoom image should not zoomed further. Here is my code.

```
    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (transform.ScaleX== 1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotation = angle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
            transform.ScaleX = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
            transform.ScaleY = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
        }
    }
```

After a certain level of zoom the image is getting disabled. Can anyone suggest me how to limit this zoom.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare maximum value and compare it with a new scale. Here's my example:

```
private readonly double maxScale = 5;

private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (transform.ScaleX == 1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Rotation = angle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
        double newScale = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
        if (newScale > maxScale)
            newScale = maxScale;
        transform.ScaleX = newScale;
        transform.ScaleY = newScale;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code that worked is here.

`private double maxScale =10;
private double minScale =0.2;
private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            transform.Rotation = angle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
            double newScale = scale * e.DistanceRatio;
            if (newScale > maxScale)
                newScale = maxScale;
            if (newScale < minScale)
                newScale = minScale;
            transform.ScaleX = newScale;
            transform.ScaleY = newScale;
        }`